# How to bake(convert) bones as FK from IK in Blender

Tags: three.js, blender, blender-2.67

How can I convert from IK(Inverse Kinematics) to FK (Forward Kinematics) in Blender?

[image]

I am trying to export a model which has skeletal animations, to THREE.js. However, It does not support IK. therefore, I need to convert all bones into FK.

Does anyone know any solutions?

Thanks! Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found, Bake Action can be bake all frames as IKs. But I suppose, there are better solution...

If you'd like to bake all frames, see the following link.
http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?308277-bake-ik-to-fk

> From the pose menu select Animation -> Bake action with "Clear
>   constraints" and "visual keying" checked. You should get baked Actions
>   that you can see in the graph editor for each bone. This won't
>   transfer from one rig to another, but I assume you can work on copies.

Answer (score 1):

One of the issues with using `Bake Action` is that it generates a bunch of keyframes in between your original keyframes.

I wrote an open source Blender Addon that generates an FK rig from your IK rig, without creating any additional keyframes.

Hope it helps! - https://github.com/chinedufn/blender-iks-to-fks