# ThreeJS GLB IK Animation Exporting

Tags: animation, three.js, blender

Why would IK animations in ThreeJS not reflect what is happening in Blender?

In Blender, the connected bones move correctly using IK.  In ThreeJS, none of the connected bones move and the only thing that happens is the vertices stretch based around where my IK controller bone is moving.

I assure you I'm doing everything pertaining to the armature correctly in Blender.  I can do it with my eyes closed at this point.  My guess is something isn't right when the animation keyframes are exported to GLB format.

I'm using ThreeJS R100.  I've tried different versions of Blender from 2.74 to 2.8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bake(convert) bones as FK from IK in Blender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748593/how-to-bakeconvert-bones-as-fk-from-ik-in-blender)

Answer (score 1):

OK, so after researching this issue further, I found a solution.  The answer to the following thread fixed it for me for Blender version 2.74:

[How to bake(convert) bones as FK from IK in Blender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748593/how-to-bakeconvert-bones-as-fk-from-ik-in-blender)

Comment: In that case, flag your question as being a duplicate of the one you found.